# How to avoid cartesian product with NOT IN condition?

Tags: hive, hiveql

My query looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE a.col NOT IN (SELECT col FROM B)
```

When I execute the query I get the following error:

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10052]: In strict mode, cartesian product is not allowed. If you really want to perform the operation, set hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict

Where is the cartesian product in my query and how can I avoid this error?

Comment: Your question looks contradictory. Here NOT IN = cartesian product, so I think you should rather ask how to avoid NOT IN.

Comment: Try joining instead - `select a.* from a left join b on a.col = b.col where.col is null`.

Comment: ...or a NOT EXISTS clause with correlated sub-query (which will be rewritten as a "join" against an in-memory hashmap)

Comment: @stevenl, add the execution plan to your post

Answer (score 0):

you can bypass not in completely and use 'except'

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE a.col except (SELECT * FROM a WHERE a.col IN (SELECT col FROM B))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve your task using left join

```
select a.* from a left outer join b on a.col = b.col where.col is NULL
```